# OC4J orion-application.xml - elements and attributes mapped to deployment plan properties

Tags: xml, oracle, deployment, configuration, oc4j

I read in oracle docs a sentence like this:

> "Each property maps to an element attribute in the orion-application.xml descriptor."

These properties are from deployment plan and I need to know what is the name of the element in orion-application.xml which is mapped to webSiteBinding property (from deployment plan).

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to bind a war file to a specific address (e.g.  http://application-server.com/myapp/ 
- you can specify that in application.xml.  No need to use orion-application.xml for that.   orion-application.xml is usually used for non j2ee spec things like jazn settings - compiler and library instructions, jmx, ejb compile instructions, etc..).  The closest thing I can guess at from your question is you can specify the

```
<web-module id>
```

in orion-application.xml. Which looks like this:

```
<web-module id="my-app" path="myapp.war" />
```

But I don't think that is what your after.  I think you just want to know  in application.xml.  Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN' 'http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd'>
<application>
    <display-name>My Application</display-name>
    <description>My Really Awesome Application</description>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>myapp.war</web-uri> 

            <context-root>/myapp</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```